# Airflow DAG does not start

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have created a couple of DAGs, almost identical, just to test scheduling.
Created the DAG files on 21 June 2023, at 1:22 and 1:57 AM (night, local time in Ukraine).
Their start times:
`start_date = datetime(2023, 6, 21, 10, 0, 0)` and `start_date = datetime(2023, 6, 21, 9, 30, 0)`
and `schedule_interval = '@daily'` for both.

So, they should run on 22 June 2023 at 10:00 AM and 9:30 AM, that is start_date + schedule_interval.

Now is 22 June 2023, 14:20 (local time), none of these DAGS has started.

The "Next run" in the UI shows 2023-06-22 00:00:00 (this is wrong anyway).

I use a docker-compose example from a course on Udemy to launch AirFlow in Docker, and the version of AirFlow is 2.4.2 (I know, this is not the last one).

Did I miss something, am I unaware of something, or Airflow scheduling does not work at all?
[image: a screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The `@daily` schedule interval is always for midnight, that's why you see the "next dag run" at midnight

In order to set the required run hour, you need to provide a "cron" like expression instead of `@daily`

for example:

- Run at 10AM   - `0 10 * * *`
- Run at 9:30AM - `30 9 * * *`

Comment: +1 for @saar-levy answer. For more details, your DAG will run at start_date + schedule_interval.

So, if you set the start_date as datetime(2023, 6, 21, 10, 0, 0) and the schedule_interval as '@daily', it will run at datetime(2023, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0).